# Run a sync function async in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, ffi, dart-ffi

I'm using the new Dart FFI with a Rust library, but the call to the library blocks, but my flutter app should run while the call is executing.
So I need to convert an sync function to an async function.
I already tried isolates and I think that should be a possible solution, but I wasn't able to achieve my goal.
Is there a way to convert this sync function to an async function?

Comment: Dart doesn't expose multiple threads, so the only way to not block the main Dart thread in Dart code is to use a Dart isolate.  There are helper functions that might make this easier (e.g. [`compute`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute.html)).  Alternatively, you perhaps could make an asynchronous wrapper on the Rust side and spawn a thread there. (I'm not experienced with Dart FFI nor with Rust so don't know how feasible that is.)

Comment: That was also my thought, but I think I found another way (really ugly but yeah) to achieve it, but loading the library on every call is definitely not what I want.

Comment: Jan, how did you manage to get it done? Could you share some code for the same if you have any!

Comment: I wasn't able to accomplish it, but my requirements changed anyway so I didn't look further into it.